# How do I delete an Imported Snippet in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, code-snippets

I imported a snippet, and I want it gone.  Problem is that the Snippet Manager has the Remove button grayed out when I go in and try to remove it, any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

Chances are that code snippet was imported to Program Files folder (e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Web\Snippets\CSS\1033\CSS) instead of C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Code Snippets

Snippet Manager displays the location of selected snippet, just go there, delete it manually and restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Why do they still have a remove button?!  My snippets located in my user location C:\Users\<MYUSER>\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is because you can only remove directories and not individual snippets (at least from the Code Snippets Manager, you know, Microsoft style!):

> To remove a **directory** from the Code Snippet Manager,  select the
>   **directory** that you want to remove.

Reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ybhaktf(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: It is not a bug, it's a feature! XD

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu users, please remove snippet files in ~/.config/Code/User/snippets
Not sure if applicable for other Linux distributions.